# How to make point size independent from grouping in lattice plotting

Tags: r, plot, lattice

Say I want to make a plot of a series of points and of different size, using `xyplot` like:

```
> xyplot(1:6 ~ 1:6, cex = 1:6)
```

And the plot comes like

[image: f1]

But when I add groups to the plot, the sizes of the points are homogenous within each group.

```
> g <- c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C')
> xyplot(1:6 ~ 1:6, groups = g, cex = 1:6)
```

[image: f2]

Also, if I use `|` to group, it comes that in each facet the size of the points goes again from the first value in the `cex`

```
> xyplot(1:6 ~ 1:6 | g, cex = 1:6)
```

[image: f3]

So is there any solution that I could make the `cex` independent from `groups` and `|`, for example in the `groups` example I hope to see a plot like the first plot with color difference only.

Answer (score 5):

Well this works:

```
library(lattice)    
g <- c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C')

xyplot(1:6 ~ 1:6, groups = g,
       panel=function(x,y,subscripts,...) {
       panel.superpose(x,y,subscripts,...,
         panel.groups=function(x,y,subscripts,group.number,...){
               panel.xyplot(x,y,cex=subscripts,col=group.number)}
       )
    }
)
```

`subscripts` keeps track of the index of the whole data set (for point size) and `group.number` the index of the groups (for color).